# Django-like abstract database API for non-Django projects

Tags: python, database, django, orm, django-models

I love the abstract database API that comes with Django, I was wondering if I could use this (or something similar) to model, access, and manage my (postgres) database for my non-Django Python projects.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you're looking for is an [object-relational mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (ORM). Django has its own, built-in.

To use Django's ORM by itself:

- [Using the Django ORM as a standalone component](http://jystewart.net/process/2008/02/using-the-django-orm-as-a-standalone-component/)
- [Use Django ORM as standalone](http://pascal.nextrem.ch/2008/08/17/use-django-orm-as-standalone/)
- [Using settings without setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module)

If you want to use something else:

- [What are some good Python ORM solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428/what-are-some-good-python-orm-solutions)

Comment: Simple, accurate, and straight to the point. Maybe add two lines on what's an ORM, for the heck of completeness? :)

Answer (score 6):

Popular stand-alone ORMs for Python:

- [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)
- [SQLObject](http://www.sqlobject.org/)
- [Storm](https://storm.canonical.com/)

They all support MySQL and PostgreSQL (among others).

Comment: +1: SQLAlchemy -- not quite as sexy as Django ORM, but easier to tie to an existing SQL database.

Comment: +1 on SQLAlchemy also. I don't see the point in using it in Django, due to the fine integration of its own ORM with its other parts. But SQLAlchemy specializes in exactly what you're looking for, and does that one thing extremely well.

Answer (score 2):

I especially like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) with following tools:

- [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/) (declarative syntax)
- [Migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/) (schema migration)

They really remind me of [ActiveRecord](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/).