# How to generate basic CRUD functionality in python given a database tables

Tags: python, database, desktop, crud

I want to develop a desktop application using python with basic crud operation. Is there any library in python that can generate a code for CRUD functionality and user interface given a database table.

Comment: You could use `Django`, but otherwise, you will have to use `wxPython` , `PyGTK` or `PyQT` manually

Comment: @voyager: Please post your answer as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully, this won't be the best option you end up with, but, in the tradition of using web-interfaces for desktop applications,  you could always try [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/).  I would particularLY take a look at the [`inspectdb`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) command, which will generate the ORM code for you.

The advantage is that it won't require that much code to get off the ground, and if you just want to use it from the desktop, you don't need a webserver; you can use the provided test server.  The bundled admin site is easy to get off the ground, and flexible up to a point; past which people seem to invest a lot of time battling it (probably a testimony to how helpful it is at first).

There are many disadvantages, not the least of which is the possibility of having to use html/javascript/css when you want to start customizing a lot.

Comment: "flexible up to a point; past which people seem to invest a lot of time battling it"  Yes, this is why it is hard to make the decision of whether to use such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would consider borrowing django's ORM, but then again, I'm already familiar with it.

Having said that, I like working with it, it's usable outside the framework, and it will give you mysql, postgres, or sqlite support. You could also hook up the django admin site to your models and have a web-based editor.

There are surely other ORMs and code generators out there too (I hope some python gurus will point some out, I'm kind of curious).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something really small and simple, I like the [Autumn](http://autumn-orm.org/) ORM.

If you use the Django ORM, you can use the automatically-generated Django admin interface, which is really nice.  It's basically a web-based GUI for browsing and editing records in your database.

If you think you will need advanced SQL features, SQLAlchemy is a good way to go.  I suspect for a desktop application, Django or Autumn would be better.

There are other Python ORMs, such as Storm.  Do a Google search on "python ORM".  See also the discussion on this web site: [[What are some good Python ORM solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428/what-are-some-good-python-orm-solutions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428/what-are-some-good-python-orm-solutions)