# Django DB Settings 'Improperly Configured' Error

Tags: python, django

Django (1.5) is workin' fine for me, but when I fire up the Python interpreter (Python 3) to check some things, I get the weirdest error when I try importing - `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 36, in _setup
    settings_module = os.environ[ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/os.py", line 450, in __getitem__
    value = self._data[self.encodekey(key)]
KeyError: b'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if settings.DATABASES and DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 52, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 45, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, 
  but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment 
  variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() 
  before accessing settings.
```

How could it be improperly configured, when it works fine outside the Python interpreter? In my Django settings, the `DATABASES` settings are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'django_db', # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'zamphatta',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword91',
        'HOST': '', # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '', # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

...how is this improperly configured?

Comment: Came across this when setting up a new project. I found it helpful to do `unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. I was running into an issue where I had set the env var in my .bashrc

Answer (score 266, accepted):

You can't just fire up Python and check things, Django doesn't know what project you want to work on. You have to do one of these things:

- Use `python manage.py shell`
- Use `django-admin.py shell --settings=mysite.settings` (or whatever settings module you use)
- Set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable in your OS to `mysite.settings`
- (This is removed in Django 1.6) Use `setup_environ` in the python interpreter:

  ```
  from django.core.management import setup_environ
  from mysite import settings

  setup_environ(settings)
  ```

Naturally, the first way is the easiest.

Comment: Thanks! That wasn't quite clear to me in the documentation, or maybe I read it & forgot by the time I needed to do it.

Comment: Oddly it can't seem to find the 'mysite.settings' file, but I can see it sitting right there as mysite/settings.py. Ugh! I'm beginning to hate Django.

Comment: completly strange to me too, because the function has some kind of static functionallaty so why setup this settings...

Comment: @Pavel Anossov      in 1.6.2 none of these works >>> from django.core.management import setup_environ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> and sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~/Documents/Projects/FirstBlog$ django-admin.py shell --settings=FirstBlog.settings / ImportError: Could not import settings 'FirstBlog.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named FirstBlog.settings

ImportError: cannot import name setup_environ

Comment: Yes, `setup_environ` is removed in 1.6, but `--settings` should work. Are you sure your settings are in further `FirstBlog.settings`, and not just in `settings` in the current directory?

Comment: None of the above worked for me, but this one did: `$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="my_project.settings"`

Comment: Oh, and one of these `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:'pwd'"`

Comment: In **PyCharm** the place to do this is Run | Edit Configurations | (e.g. Unittests in project) | Configuration | Environment | Environment variables:  `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=(project directory name).settings`

Comment: this has been happening to me now that I split time w django and flask lol

Comment: I'm using Django 1.11 and the part of this answer featuring `setup_environ` doesn't work for me, but this question and answer does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048963/alternative-to-the-deprecated-setup-environ-for-one-off-django-scripts

Comment: @Thumbz `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="my_project.settings"` where did you put this?

Comment: Any update on this thread? None of this works for me.

Answer (score 41):

In your python shell/ipython do:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()
```

Comment: `Apps aren't loaded yet.`

Answer (score 26):

In 2017 with django 1.11.5 and python 3.6 (*from the comment this also works with Python 2.7*):

```
import django
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
django.setup()
```

The `.py` in which you put this code should be in `mysite` (the parent one)

Comment: Thanks a lot, none of the other solutions have worked in my case

Comment: Work with python 2.7 too

Comment: This `.py` should be placed at the **root**, which means it is along with manage.py. How do I place it inside random folders?

Comment: It should be noted that this will only work if you put it at the top of your file, if you put it inside of something like `if __name__ == "__main__":` it won't work correctly :)

Answer (score 12):

On Django 1.9, I tried `django-admin runserver` and got the same error, but when I used `python manage.py runserver` I got the intended result. This may solve this error for a lot of people!

Comment: same, on django 1.10, but while trying to run the command loaddata

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I got this when trying to run Django tests through PyCharm. I think it is because PyCharm does not load the initial Django project settings, i.e. those that `manage.py shell` runs initially. One can add them to the start of the testing script or just run the tests using `manage.py test`.

Versions:

- Python 3.5 (in virtualenv)
- PyCharm 2016.3.2 Professional
- Django 1.10

Answer (score 3):

in my own case in django 1.10.1 running on python2.7.11, I was trying to start the server using `django-admin runserver` instead of `manage.py runserver` in my project directory.

Answer (score 0):

For people using IntelliJ, with these settings I was able to query from the shell (on windows).

[image]