# DB error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: django, django-settings, django-fixtures

Getting this error when trying to create a fixture and run next command in terminal:

```
django-admin.py dumpdata data.json
```

Full traceback:

```
(project)litwisha@litwisha:~/PycharmProjects/test_project$ django-admin.py dumpdata data.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/litwisha/.virtualenvs/project/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/home/litwisha/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/litwisha/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/litwisha/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/home/litwisha/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 258, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/home/litwisha/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 252, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/home/litwisha/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 60, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/litwisha/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 151, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/home/litwisha/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/litwisha/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556596/3525271), but doesn't work:

When writing in shell:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
```

get error:

```
RuntimeError: Settings already configured.
```

Maybe it because I use `virtualenv`? But I tried it without `virtualenv`, but it doesn't work. I use IDE `PyCharm`

```
settings.py:
"""
Django settings for test_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'r1n@)rahbrh6t1hb-mn_83c^7ai@ij&7d8m8mo7tdm&5q#o5t&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'test_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'test_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'test1',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1111',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Can you share your settings file?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/)

Comment: @Gocht, I need to create a fixture for testing purposes: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading]

Comment: For testing you should use a [test database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database)