# Writing your first Django app, error with from . import views

Tags: python, django

I'm started learning python-django and I would like create my first django app.
I'm following the Django 1.8 tutorial. In my project "mysite", there is a source folder "polls". In the folder there is "views.py" module where a "index" function is defined. And there is a "urls.py" file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), 
]
```

Now i'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/ukasz/Pulpit/Python/mysite/polls/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import views
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

**Edit: Updated with new information provided by woljako in an answer**

my mysite/ursl.py:

```
 from django.conf.urls import include, url
 from django.contrib import admin

 urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
 url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
 ]
```

and I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ukasz/Pulpit/Python/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
  url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'polls'
```

I added to INSTALLED_APPS app 'polls', but still it didn't help

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
]
```

Comment: in `from . import views` try to replace `.` with `mysite.polls` or `.polls`

Comment: thanks, it works, but I have still problem, now with * mysite/urls.py*

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: You'd better update your question with `mysite/urls.py` and the error you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that can cause this. I have two possible solutions that are not mentioned yet.

1. Try to replace `url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),` with `url(r'^polls/', include('mysite.polls.urls')),`
2. Have you remembered to include an `__init__.py` file inside the `polls` folder? This is required for the import to work. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for reference. Simply create an empty file with the name `__init__.py`. Note the double underscores.

Please let me know if this solves you problems.

Comment: ehhh, another problem appears, current error:   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: I think this solves the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556499/django-db-settings-improperly-configured-error

Comment: I have just started learning django and I don't know how to use first option which is the easiest, I write python manage.py shell in console and what is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

Try to register polls in your applications in settings.py. Something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6a0W.jpg)

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In Polls/urls.py add the this line at top

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

And replace the `from . import views` with `from polls import views`.
I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

In Polls/urls.py
Add the this line at top
"from django.contrib import admin"
And  "from polls import views"
I hope this will work.