# environment variable for django settings?

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I've been using Django for over a year and have never needed to 'define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as I am asked to do in the following error message:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: setUpClass (__main__.SmokeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1026, in setUpClass
    if not connections_support_transactions():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 991, in connections_support_transactions
    for conn in connections.all())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 227, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 224, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 157, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I am using Windows command line.

I tried running

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556499/django-db-settings-improperly-configured-error), but this didn't help.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: Do you have these DB settings in your settings.py? And also, were you using an OS other than windows and loading your settings from a .env file?

Comment: @MukundGandlur  I have the default sqlite in my settings.py, haven't altered it.  I've been using windows the whole time.

Comment: How are you running the code that leads to this error ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  in the command line I am in my app directory, I run python tests.py

Comment: How exactly are you running these tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "@brunodesthuilliers in the command line I am in my app directory, I run python tests.py "

Well that's not going to work (at least not that easily). Why don't you just use the builtin management "test" command ?

```
 #> cd your/project/root 
 #> python manage.py test
```

cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure in your **manage.py** have something like this

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "projectname.settings")
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/

Comment: Yes I certainly do

Comment: I see from your comment on your question if you want to do like that should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853649/executing-python-script-from-django-shell