# Can't run Django template engine - Django

Tags: python, django

```
from django import template

t = template.Template("My name is {{ name }}.")
c = template.Context({'name' : 'Yasmika'})
print(t.render(t))
```

I'm learning the basics of Python Django. When I'm trying to run Django template, Python interpreter gives me this error. How can I fix this?

```
C:\Users\YasmikaSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/YasmikaSH/Desktop/lern_django/lern_django/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/YasmikaSH/Desktop/lern_django/lern_django/test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    t = template.Template("My name is {{ name }}.")
  File "C:\Users\YasmikaSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 184, in __init__
    engine = Engine.get_default()
  File "C:\Users\YasmikaSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 76, in get_default
    django_engines = [engine for engine in engines.all()
  File "C:\Users\YasmikaSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 89, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\YasmikaSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 86, in __iter__
    return iter(self.templates)
  File "C:\Users\YasmikaSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\YasmikaSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 29, in templates
    self._templates = settings.TEMPLATES
  File "C:\Users\YasmikaSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\YasmikaSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting TEMPLATES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: No. But I will not understand it even if I read it.

Comment: That's not a useful mentality when writing code... Django isn't really meant to be used outside of a Django project. You can configure it to work from within a single `.py` file, but it takes some effort.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556499/django-db-settings-improperly-configured-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImproperlyConfigured: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO\_SETTINGS\_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying

```
print(t.render(c))
```

Do `python manage.py shell`

```
In [74]: from django import template

In [75]: t = template.Template("My name is {{ name }}.")

In [76]: c = template.Context({'name' : 'Yasmika'})

In [77]: print(t.render(c))
My name is Yasmika.
```

Comment: Exactly, running `t.render(t)` makes no sense. +1

Answer (score 1):

Django isn't really meant to be used outside of a Django project (or something that looks like one). You can start a Django project by following the ["Writing your first Django app" tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/). Once you have a project setup, launch a shell by running:

```
$ python manage.py shell
```

This loads a Python shell with Django fully configured to use your settings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE setting defined in your environment.

Have a look here for the documentation related to the settings module -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

Your can set it like this

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<yoursite>.settings
```

When you use Django, you have to tell it which settings you’re using. Do this by using an environment variable, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

The value of DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE should be in Python path syntax, e.g. mysite.settings. Note that the settings module should be on the Python import search path.