# Could'nt import Django

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I started my django project without activating my virtualenv django-admin startproject my_project and django-admin startapp my_app. Everythiing went fine, till i closed my terminal, and stopped the serveer. I wanted to restart my server, but this message is still coming up. i tried to install the virtualenv still the same problem,

```
File "./manage.py", line 17, in <module>
"Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and 
available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to 
activate a virtual environment?
```

Please what could be the problem and how to fix this ??

Comment: is Django an importable module?  Sounds like the current scope cant find it, which means you might need to install it by way of `pip install django`

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: django in ./myshop/myshop/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./myshop/myshop/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django)

Comment: check if its available in your env. `./manage.py shell` -> `import django` That should send an error like `ImportError: No module named django`. Are you sure you are in the same env as before? Its quite easy to navigate in the wrong path especially if you are not familiar with the terminal

Comment: indeed it's ouputting Non module named django. Actually i ddint activate the virtualenv beforestarting my project, just went stratight with the django-admin startproject my_project and django-admin startproject my_app

Comment: yes in this case navigate the correct path start the env with `source env/bin/activate` and `pip install -e django/`

Comment: did all these then whem im trying to run djang-admin runserver, i got this . django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: @Patcho please use "@hanstheFranz" or I won't see you wrote something and can't help you. Yes you need a settings file. But this should be provided. Try to run `./manage.py runserver`. If you don't have a project yet you need to start one with `django-admin startproject myproject`. If you have one go into main folder and look for the settings.py file. maybe this helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556499/django-db-settings-improperly-configured-error

Answer (score 0):

You should run `pip install django` at terminal after active the virtualenv.

Comment: Hi, Thanks all. I fixed it.  just needed to create a new virtual env, then install djnago and restart  the old project. Anyway, i end up creating a docker image for my project..