# Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured error in my Django project

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, sqlite

I am attempting to change my database settings in my django project from sqlite3 to mysql.

I edited the database object in my settings.py file :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Identity',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD': ''
    }
}
```

I ran django-admin dbshell and got this error :

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
>   line 39, in _setup
>       % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
>   DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the
>   environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I followed the instruction from this [answer to use settings.configure()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556499/django-db-settings-improperly-configured-error)

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
```

It returned this message :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
>   line 63, in configure
>       raise RuntimeError('Settings already configured.') RuntimeError: Settings already configured.

When I ran `python3 manage.py shell` it gives me this error :

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb
>   module: No module named 'MySQLdb'

All I want to do is use mySql instead of sqlite db.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems  **MySQLdb** packages are missing,
can you check this package are installed

> apt-get install mysql-server
>
> apt-get install mysql-client
>
> apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

In your virtual environment,conform mysql client installed

> pip install mysqlclient

then do the mysql configuration in **settings.py**

```
   DATABASES = {
      'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'NAME': 'test_db',#database name
      'HOST': '127.0.0.1',#
      'PORT': '3306',#mysql port
      'USER': 'root',#mysql username
      'PASSWORD': 'test123',#mysql password
       'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        'charset': 'utf8mb4',
         }
     }
  }
```