# Django Exception: Improperly Configured

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-settings

I have seen this in Stack overflow so many times, but i don't know how it relates to the problem i am facing. I am using django 1.11

Here is the full error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kaijieang/Coding/MyLife/MyLife/ministry/views/youth.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ministry.models import Caregroup
  File "/Users/kaijieang/Coding/MyLife/MyLife/ministry/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .attendance import Attendance
  File "/Users/kaijieang/Coding/MyLife/MyLife/ministry/models/attendance.py", line 3, in <module>
    from MyLife.models.base_model import BaseModel
  File "/Users/kaijieang/Coding/MyLife/MyLife/MyLife/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from MyLife.models import base_model as BaseModel
  File "/Users/kaijieang/Coding/MyLife/MyLife/MyLife/models/base_model.py", line 4, in <module>
    class BaseModel(models.Model):
  File "/Users/kaijieang/Coding/MyLife/MyLife/MyLife/models/base_model.py", line 5, in BaseModel
    created = models.DateField('Date Created', auto_now_add=True)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/MyLife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1185, in __init__
    super(DateField, self).__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/MyLife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/anaconda3/envs/MyLife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/MyLife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I tried to run this file as part of testing something out:

```
from ministry.models import Caregroup


def save_model():
    cg = Caregroup(name='a', alias='v', school='c', size=20)

    cg.save()
```

I am trying something out on a pyCharm IDE and i ran into such an error. May i know what is causing this error? My settings have been properly configured:

```
wsgi.py:

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MyLife.settings")
```

Comment: you need to export setting via terminal to save in OS.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool Is it something similar to the solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556499/django-db-settings-improperly-configured-error? Because i tried that and it still did not work

Comment: did you tried `settings.configure()`  ?

Comment: Yupp, that as well!

Comment: now do `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="my_project.settings"` and this will solve your issue.

Comment: I get invalid syntax error. Am i doing it wrongly? I am pasting the piece of code straight into the ipython console

Comment: no, just put it in linux terminal

Comment: It still does not work

Comment: Seems like the error originate from the import statement

Answer (score 0):

you just need to run

```
$ export {path_to_bashfile} DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="MyLife.settings"
```

in terminal and it will work.

[image]

Comment: It still doesnt work. I suspect the issue lies with me being unable to a python file within the app folder directly.

Comment: Which part of the script? I am not sure which part you need to see, btu i have provided what i think is the issue