# I do not understand where the slashes in json come from in the server's response

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest, http, hug

In the main function, i call a function in which another application is called, as a result i get data in json format. 
But I don’t understand where the slashes come from in front of each double quotation "

in the browser, I see data with quotes
**Example:** `{\"192.168.43.1\":[\"53\":{\"state\":\"open\"...`

If I do not send the data but write to the file, data is written to the file WITHOUT slashes
**Example:** `{"192.168.43.1":["53":{"state":"open"...`

This is normal? 
How do I remove the slashes? 
This data must accept
    another application and deserialize them.

```
def get_ip(ip, port):
   return os.system("some_app")

@hug.get('/scan')
def main(ip: hug.types.text, port: hug.types.text):
    json = get_ip(ip, port)

    #JUST FOR TEST WITH PARAM safe=False                                                
    return JsonResponse("{\"192.168.1.1\":[\"80\":{\"state\":\"open\",\"reason\":\"syn-ack\",\"name\":\"http\",\"product\":\"\"}]}", safe=False)
```

Errors without parametr **safe=False:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
 self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/falcon/api.py", line 244, in __call__
responder(req, resp, **params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/hug/interface.py", line 793, in __call__
raise exception
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/hug/interface.py", line 766, in __call__
self.render_content(self.call_function(input_parameters), context, request, response, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/hug/interface.py", line 703, in call_function
return self.interface(**parameters)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/hug/interface.py", line 100, in __call__
return __hug_internal_self._function(*args, **kwargs)
File "script.py", line 181, in main
return JsonResponse("{\"192.168.1.1\":[\"80\":{\"state\":\"open\",\"reason\":\"syn-ack\",\"name\":\"http\",\"product\":\"\"}]}")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 552, in __init__
'In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the '
TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.
```

Errors with parametr **safe=False**:

```
return JsonResponse("{\"192.168.1.1\":[\"80\":{\"state\":\"open\",\"reason\":\"syn-ack\",\"name\":\"http\",\"product\":\"\"}]}", safe=False)


 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/falcon/api.py", line 244, in __call__
responder(req, resp, **params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/hug/interface.py", line 793, in __call__
raise exception
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/hug/interface.py", line 766, in __call__
self.render_content(self.call_function(input_parameters), context, request, response, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/hug/interface.py", line 703, in call_function
return self.interface(**parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/hug/interface.py", line 100, in __call__
return __hug_internal_self._function(*args, **kwargs)
File "script.py", line 181, in main
return JsonResponse("{\"192.168.1.1\":[\"80\":{\"state\":\"open\",\"reason\":\"syn-ack\",\"name\":\"http\",\"product\":\"\"}]}", safe=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 559, in __init__
super().__init__(content=data, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 291, in __init__
self.content = content
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 321, in content
content = self.make_bytes(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 236, in make_bytes
return bytes(value.encode(self.charset))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 85, in charset
return settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting 
DEFAULT_CHARSET, but settings are not configured. You must either define the 
environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() 
before accessing settings.
```

Comment: These are called "backslashes", btw.

Comment: decode your json it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Your `return "result {json}"` would return string value which contains json. Since returned value is string, browser shows you extra backslashes in order to properly handle double quotes.

To solve this problem you could handle string response in client side and extract json values from string.

```
JSON.parse(response);
```

But since another application is expecting json format you'd better to use `JsonResponse` to make sure return response is not string but json format

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse(json)
```

Comment: Does not work, tried to deserialize even like this:                                                          return JsonResponse("{\"192.168.1.1\":[\"80\":{\"state\":\"open\",\"reason\":\"syn-ack\",\"name\":\"http\",\"product\":\"\"}]}")

Comment: @user3686478 how do you run your server? are you running it directly from django or  just from python shell?

Comment: @user3686478 `ImproperlyConfigured` problem is not directly related to json problem. Check so for possible solutions, for ex [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556499/django-db-settings-improperly-configured-error)