# Error in django interactive shell on pydev eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, shell

When I click on `django --> shell with django environment` give me:

```
from django.core import management;
import test1.settings as settings;
management.setup_environ(settings)
```

Error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in  
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setup_environ'

- Eclipse 4.3.1
- Python 2.6
- Django 1.6

Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you provide some info on what you've tried to fix the issue?

Comment: Also, maybe you can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048963/alternative-to-the-deprecated-setup-environ-for-one-off-django-scripts

Comment: shell work on manage.py shell but it don't have code completion .because i'm newbie code completion is very helpful for me.

Comment: That didn't make sense to me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: any luck on this, am having the same prob ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a conflict between your version of PyDev and your version of Django. In Django 1.6, django.core.management.setup_environ() was removed. This issue was fixed in PyDev on Feb 4, here: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/f546ac4

If you update your installed version of PyDev to the latest (currently 3.4.1) this should begin to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this on Django version 1.10.4 in Eclipse Neon with PyDev 4.1.  The reason is that the script in Preferences -> PyDev -> Interactive Console -> Initial Commands evaluates Django version 1.10 as less than 1.5 and executes the commands for an invalid version of Django.  The workaround solution is to delete all Django interpreter commands for the wrong version and only execute commands for version 1.7 and above.