# Getting to interactive Django shell in PyDev

Tags: python, django, eclipse, shell, pydev

I can open an interactive shell from the command line, just not from PyDev inside Eclipse. Clicking through `Django --> Shell with django environment` I get the following output:

```
import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))
C:\Python27\python.exe 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
PyDev console: using default backend (IPython not available).

from django.core import management;import carbon_factors.settings as settings;management.setup_environ(settings)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setup_environ'
```

To try and resolve this I have updated PyDev to 3.2.0 with no change to the output. I'm using Django 1.6.

I have looked at the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107144/error-in-django-interactive-shell-on-pydev-eclipse) which pointed me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048963/alternative-to-the-deprecated-setup-environ-for-one-off-django-scripts). However the accepted answer seems to have already be built into Django/PyDev as the line it suggests to change in `manage.py` is already changed.

Comment: Did you set your manage.py & settings.py in Project Properties -> PyDev-Django?

Comment: Yes. Or at least something did - they've both been set when I check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setup_environ` has been deprecated in Django 1.6.  See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/internals/deprecation/#id1).

As far as I can tell, PyDev has hardcoded this method of starting a Django shell into the right click project -> "shell with Django environment" menu item.  This is an issue that PyDev needs to address (hopefully by simplifying whatever they are doing under the hood with that command to just "python manage.py shell"!)  I don't believe their menu command currently calls manage.py, which is why the other answers didn't work for you.

**Option 1**
As a hacky workaround, add "from django.conf import settings; settings.configure()" to the initial interpreter commands in Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interactive Console.  You'll still see the error but at least you'll have your settings.

**Option 2**
In Window->Preferences->Interpreter->Environment tab, add an environment variable "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" with the Python dotted path to your settings file (exclude the '.py' at the end).

Comment: I had the same problem. I had already tried option 2 without any luck, but option 1 did the trick.

Comment: I am using Neon and Django 1.10. When I was trying Option 1, I saw Neon test version in a way that cannot detect 1.10 correctly. I added 
"""
if '1.10' in django.get_version():
 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 application = get_wsgi_application()"""

To the beggining. But now I get "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty."

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of having an up-to-date answer, this works fine for me with Django 1.8 and Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 1):

For Django 1.10 and Eclipse Neon.
Following [Option 1 from andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22152776/1708819).

My settings file is inside *myproject/config/settings/local.py*.

Go to: **Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interactive Console->Initial Commands**
and replace the first line with:

```
import os; os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'config.settings.local'; import django
if '1.10' in django.get_version():
    django.setup()
```