# Django: Run process on server that updates data periodically

Tags: python, django

I have a Django web sever, on this server, I'd like to run a process (let's say every couple hours) that updates an app's database. To be more specific, my Django site hosts a large list of words that are combed from Google trends and I want to run a process on the server that updates that data periodically. I already have created this process and can run it off my machine, I don't have it on the server yet, where in a Django project may I integrate this process?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Joseph's suggestion, you can also write a custom management command (docs currently at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/), which can be invoked through manage.py. This then can be called from cron or similar.

Furthermore, if you implement Joseph's suggestion of having a standalone script, you'll need to do some setup. Pretty much exactly what's recommended on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048963/alternative-to-the-deprecated-setup-environ-for-one-off-django-scripts).

Answer (score 1):

If this script is for a specific app, you could make a `[app]/scripts/` directory. If it's for the project as a whole, you could make a `scripts` directory in the project root directory.

Then you would use a task scheduler, like `cron` if you're on *nix, to run that script however often you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Celery (http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to run a periodic task but still cron is the simplest solution.