# Django ORM manually disconnect when running outside of Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

After connecting to the Django ORM as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180415/using-django-database-layer-outside-of-django) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999300/error-with-django-database-layer-outside-of-django-1-10-7).

What's the best practice to avoid a runtime error if there already is an active connection/setup/settings already configured?

Currently if you call `settings.configure(...)` again you get an exception: `RuntimeError: Settings already configured.` I want to avoid potentially making multiple connections and this runtime error when already setup.

Is there a way to disconnect gracefully or should this be try/catched?

Comment: This has nothing to do with "connections".

Comment: Well the setup makes a connection to the db doesn't it?

Comment: No, configuring settings does not create a connection. The database backend lazily creates a thread-local connection when a query is executed, unless a connection is already active.

Comment: so `try settings.configure(...) except RuntimeError, e: print e` is the way to go?

Comment: You should just call `settings.configure()` once at the entry point of your application, or alternatively set `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` to point to your settings module if you have one.