# airflow: django / logging

Tags: django, airflow, python-logging

We're trying to use airflow with a custom django project and followed the advice of this answer [(Django) ORM in airflow - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470245/django-orm-in-airflow-is-it-possible) .  When we implemented it on airflow v1.10.11, our tasks would always fail at the part of django setup where it reconfigures logging based on django settings.  The error that we would get back looked like:

```
[2020-09-02 18:54:29,344] {local_task_job.py:102} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGKILL
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why / how airflow is detecting changes to the logging configuration and then killing the task?