# Django model outside of django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a non django project for which i would like to use the django models for data access layer.

Added the models lib in `requirements.txt`
`django-model-utils==3.1.1`

And code set it up like below:

```python
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

settings.configure(
  DATABASE_ENGINE='django.db.backends.mysql',
  DATABASE_NAME='***',
  DATABASE_USER='***',
  DATABASE_PASSWORD='***',
  DATABASE_HOST='***',
  DATABASE_PORT='***')

class Bus(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    db_table = 'my_custom_bus'

  bus_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  bus_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

But when i ran the above code, i am getting the following error:
`django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

In order to fix the above error, i ran:

```python
import django  
django.setup()
```

Now when i try, i get:
`Bus doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS`

Am i missing some setting here or is there any light weight model only lib in python?

Comment: You should create the entire app structure for django. Create an app, define your models there, then import from the app.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180415/using-django-database-layer-outside-of-django

Comment: Thanks! That seems a bit heavy weight, mine is a `pants` project. Is there a light weight models library that i can use to interact with database?

Comment: I strongly recommend not to use a monolithic library like Django if the only thing you need is the ORM.  You will be in a world of pain, fighting Django's opinions all the way.  There are better choices out there, [sqlalchemy](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy) for example has a far superior ORM which will be more "pluggable".

Comment: Great! Thank you, i will try `sqlalchemy`.

Comment: @wim I disagree, and basically use Django for anything that involves a relational database setup. Though I do keep a standard project structure. Once you have done it a few times, it not many steps. And the benefit of having the admin available for populating and viewing data during development is a huge advantage. SQL Alchemy would be the obvious ORM replacement, but that has a way steeper learning curve than Django's.

Comment: In my particular case, wherein its simply a set of scripts downloading data from apis and saving in database, sqlalchemy is suiting well.

Answer (score 1):

(It's an old question, but i answer it, maybe help others.)

**option 1 (recommended)**

seeing comments, you mentions:

> In my particular case, wherein its simply a set of scripts downloading data from apis and saving in database, sqlalchemy is suiting well.

In some situations (like what you mentioned) you can use django management commands. For example if you want to do some tasks that are related to django models and should run in background. like some crontab jobs like updating database fields every 5 minutes or executing some script related to some apis that should run and update database models.

For this, create a management command like below and your good to go:

- in your app, create a folder `management`. then add an empty `__init__.py` file to it. next create another folder called `commands` in that folder and yet add another empty `__init__.py` to `commands` folder. now create your script files in `commands` folder. for example `test_script.py`.
- Now add this in `test_script.py`:

  ```
  from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

  class Command(BaseCommand):

      def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
          # Add your script codes here.
  ```
- Now to run it, simply execute this command: `python manage.py test_command`
- for more details read [this link](https://medium.com/@frfahim/custom-management-command-in-django-b5ba1e6ea4a2)

**option 2**

There is a powerful ORM for python `sqlalchemy`. You can use it if you don't want to use any part of django or create another django and add your non-django project's code to it. But remember you need to define your django model design with sqlalchemy too. But it's not that hard to do that.

**option 3**

as my friends suggested in comments, you can config another project to use your existing django project as an app. follow [Using Django database layer outside of Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180415/using-django-database-layer-outside-of-django)