# General network MVC framework for Python

Tags: python, django, network-programming

I have been using Django for web-development, and have become quite fond of that framework. However, I would like to use a similar framework but for more general network applications. Is there such a framework? Or is it possible to modify Django to be able to have a more general network/protocol backend?

Comment: The standard library comes with `SimpleSocketServer`, here: http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html . It might be what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) should be able to help you. Take a look at [Twisted projects](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedProjects) and decide on the protocol which you are going to use.

Comment: Twisted seems to be a good general network framework, but I also want a template engine and an ORM framework too, and I like those parts in Django. For the template engine I found Jinja which seems like a good match, but I still haven't found an ORM framework as simple as the one in Django.

Comment: In terms of simplicity i found Storm to be on par with Django. Review this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428/what-are-some-good-python-orm-solutions. Autumn seems to be much simpler but pathetic documentation. Your best bet would be to go with Storm.

Comment: I have looked into the named framworks, and at the moment it looks like I will be using Twisted for network, Storm for ORM and Jinja2 for templating.