# How to store recipe information with Python

Tags: python, database, database-design

I'm very new to Python and I'm trying to write a sort of recipe organizer to get acquainted with the language.  Basically, I am unsure how how I should be storing the recipes.
For now, the information I want to store is:

- Recipe name
- Ingredient names
- Ingredient quantities
- Preparation

I've been thinking about how to do this with the built-in sqlite3, but I know nothing about database architecture, and haven't been able to find a good reference.
I suppose one table would contain recipe names and primary keys.  Preparation could be in a different table with the primary key as well.  Would each ingredient/quantity pair need its own table.

In other words, there would be a table for `ingredientNumberOne`, and each recipe's first ingredient, with the quantity, would go in there.  Then each time recipe comes along with more ingredients than there are tables, a new table would be created.

Am I even correct in assuming that sqlite3 is sufficient for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, SQLite3 is sufficient for the task.
2. Each ingredient/quantity pair does *not* need its own table.

One quick way to pick up the basics of SQL is to fiddle with the [Command Line Shell for SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) and knock around some data interactively before you start writing Python.  SQL isn't too difficult.  It *can* be difficult, when you really start flexing it, but I imagine you'll be able to learn enough for your needs pretty quickly.  IMHO the missing link in your understanding of modeling data with an RDBMS is grokking [one-to-many and many-to-many relationships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29).

Your approach would probably work, but it seems roundabout.  There are a lot of solutions to modeling that sort of data.  I'm thinking of something like:

```
TABLE recipes
    name text primary key
    preparation text

TABLE ingredients
    recipe foreign key
    name text
    quantity double
```

If you want to interact with your DB in a Pythonic way, look at [SQLalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or another [ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428/what-are-some-good-python-orm-solutions).  (My opinion is that they've been more trouble than they're worth on my own **small** projects.)

Of course, you could also make each recipe document a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) object and then [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) them all.  (Sorry, broad question - broad answer.)  This should work very well; a lot of us just jump towards SQL because our first hobby projects were web apps.

My final piece of advice (from the experience of a true non-expert) is to just start coding.  The scale of the project isn't so large that you couldn't refactor in a different method of persistence, and when you hit a wall you'll find it a lot easier to solve the real problem than a hypothetical one.

Comment: Good answer, but your comment about ORMs needs to be corrected. I think for someone who hasn't done anything with SQL yet, an ORM is a much more easier and faster way to get started with database programming.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the thorough answer.  The one-one/many, etc. was indeed very illuminating.  I see how your structure can solve the problem now.  Shelve looks pretty straightforward as well.  Sorry about the broad question, but as a beginner it just looks like an endless sea of options out there.  Sometimes the hardest part is figuring out where to start

Comment: @ms4py I don't think I can "correct" an *opinion*.  I'd agree that frameworks with built in ORMs like Django are straight-forward and delightful, but I implemented SQLalchemy for a command line app and it simply wasn't worth the complexity for my very simple use case.

Comment: There is the declarative mode of sqlalchemy which makes the data modeling as easy as with Django (http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/declarative.html). And before that there was the Elixir Layer: http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/. Very interesting in this discussion is the blog post of Armin Ronacher: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/19/sqlachemy-and-you/

Answer (score 2):

Just a general data modeling concept:  you never want to name anything "...NumberOne", "...NumberTwo".  Data models designed in this way are very difficult to query.  You'll ultimately need to visit each of N tables for 1 to N ingredients.  Also, each table in the model would ultimately have the same fields making maintenance a nightmare.

Rather, just have one ingredient table that references the "recipe" table.

Ultimately, I just realized this doesn't exactly answer the question, but you could implement this solution in Sqlite.  I just get worried when good developers start introducing bad patterns into the data model.  This comes from a guy who's been on both sides of the coin.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance--good to know some best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the Dabo framework (http://dabodev.com/)

Here's a step by step guide to building applications with it: https://docs.google.com/View?id=dg79jzmg_85f737ww6x

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to answer your own question here. From a technical standpoint, if you want to store something in Python it can be as easy as:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(myObject, myFile)
"Then read it back"
myObject = pickle.load(myFile)
```

If you happen to need something more than just data storage, then you should start looking at a database. There are a ton of databases out there, and sqlite is almost certainly up to the task.