# Python lightweight database wrapper for SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there a lightweight database wrapper in Python that I can use for SQLite. I would like something like Django's ORM, but that I can just point to a database file and it'll make the required API for me (i.e handle all the CRUD).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yeah, SQLAlchemy is great, but there are also other options. One of them is Peewee.
Very lightweight and it may fits perfectly with what you are looking for.

https://github.com/coleifer/peewee

Comment: peewee should hopefully get you there.  if you already have a database, there is a script "pwiz" that will generate model code as well: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/model-code-generation-peewee/

Comment: peewee simply easy & quick to use this.

Answer (score 13):

Some options:

[Peewee](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/peewee-a-lightweight-python-orm/)

[Storm](https://storm.canonical.com/)

[SQLObject](http://www.sqlobject.org/)

[What are some good Python ORM solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428/what-are-some-good-python-orm-solutions)

Comment: SQLALchemy - it is probably the most well known and used.

Comment: Agreed. But Simon7 already rebuffed that suggestion from Alex.

Answer (score 12):

SQLAlchemy may be what you are looking for.

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Comment: is there anything that's not so horrifically complex?

Comment: Its oldest and strong, but seems complicated and not best of best in developer friendly. yet hard deverlopment skills required compare to Peewee.

Answer (score 7):

Definitely [peewee](http://peewee.readthedocs.org). I've tried sqlalchemy but it's a mess and there is no magic.

Other ORMs are no more developed or not so good, like SQLobject, Elixir (layer on top of sqlalchemy), PonyORM.
Peewee is the best I've seen so far in the python community, and it's the closer to the main ORMs for ruby or for php.

Peewee also have many gems, like this handful shortcut

```
Person.get_or_create(name='Foo', surname='Bar')
```

that automagically take the person named 'Foo Bar' from the DB if it exists, otherwise it creates it .

Comment: After working for a year with SQLAlchemy, I can say that it is the best-developed framework at the moment. I wouldn't consider any other framework when I have to work with SQL.

Comment: Downvoted. This: "I've tried sqlalchemy but it's a mess and there is no magic." is false.

Comment: You’re definitely right. At the time where I posted my comment I thought I had everything figured out. The reality is that I knew not much and I now regret that comment. I’ve been using sqlachemy for the last two years and I can say that it is quite an awesome ORM with very good design decisions behind that.

Comment: Cool, man. That's the right attitude. I know the feeling. SQLAlchemy is powerful and with that power comes complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Just finished this very simple and cool python object oriented orm layer.

https://github.com/lxknvlk/python_orm_sqlite

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer : I have an affiliation with package, [sql30](https://pypi.org/project/sql30/), suggested here.*

[sql30](https://pypi.org/project/sql30/) can be another potential option for lightweight CRUD operations on `SQLITE` database. It is a zero weight ORM, written using only native python constructs and has no dependency on any other module which makes it great option for platforms which have limited or lagging support of Python such as ESX .

For the use case, asked in question here, user can simply

1. Create a Class object referring to database file
2. Define table schema (based on the columns of table) using simple JSON.

and you are ready for any CRUD operations.

An example is shown below.

Say the database file is `reviews.db` and one of the table in it is `reviews` which has fields of individual reviews such as `rid, header, rating and desc(iption)`. One can do the CRUD operations as below.

```
# reviews.py
from sql30 import db

class Reviews(db.Model):
    PKEY = 'rid'
    DB_SCHEMA = {
        'db_name': 'reviews.db',
        'tables': [
            {
                'name': 'reviews',
                'fields': {
                    'rid': 'uuid',
                    'header': 'text',
                    'rating': 'int',
                    'desc': 'text'
                    },
                'primary_key': 'rid'
            }]
        }
    VALIDATE_BEFORE_WRITE = True
```

One can do CRUD operations as below now.

```
>>> import os
>>> import reviews


# Create ORM layer object instance.
>>> db = reviews.Reviews()

# With this, we can create/write records to db as following.
>>> tbl = 'reviews' # select database table, you want to operate on.
>>> db.write(tbl, rid=1, header='good thing', rating=5)
>>> db.write(tbl, rid=2, header='bad thing', rating=1, desc='what a disgusting thing')

# We can then read back the records individually are as whole as shown below.

# To read all the records from a table, simply pass the table name.
>>> db.read(tbl)
[(1, 'good thing', 5, ''), (2, 'bad thing', 1, 'what a disgusting thing')]

# To read the records from table, simply pass on the condition as params.
>>> db.read(tbl, rid=1) # Get records from table WHERE rid=1
[(1, 'good thing', 5, '')]

# Get records from table WHERE rid=1 and rating=3. Note that, there is no
# restriction on the order in which condition needs to be provided. Only
# the param name should be one of the COLUMN(s) in table.
>>> db.read(tbl, rating=3, rid=1)
[]
>>> db.read(tbl, rating=5, rid=1)
[(1, 'good thing', 5, '')]

# If we try to add another record with same primary key, it will error out.
>>> db.write(tbl, rid=1, header='good thing', rating=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  ...
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: reviews.rid

# Updating the record is also possible by providing condition for records and updated values.
>>> where = {'rid': 2}
>>> db.update(tbl, condition=where, header='average item', rating=2)
>>> db.read(tbl)
[(1, 'good thing', 5, ''), (2, 'average item', 2, 'what a disgusting thing')]

# Deleteing the records is possble with any level of filtering.
>>> db.remove(tbl, rid=1)
>>> db.read(tbl)
[(2, 'average item', 2, 'what a disgusting thing')]

# At this point, however, all of your records are being maintained by SQLITE in-memory.
# However, commit API can be used to persist them in the DB file.
>>> db.commit()
```

Parallel operations are allowed and handled well as long as DB connection is used within same thread, which is essentially `sqlite` module requirement. Example of this is [here](https://github.com/gitvipin/sql30/blob/master/sql30/tests/scale.py).

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [RabaDB](https://github.com/tariqdaouda/rabaDB). It has arguably one of the simplest interfaces out there.

```
class Human(R.Raba) :
        _raba_namespace = 'test_namespace'

        #Everything that is not a raba object is primitive
        name = rf.Primitive()
        age = rf.Primitive()
        city = rf.Primitive()

        #Only Cars can fit into this relation
        cars = rf.Relation('Car')

        #best friend can only be a human
        bestFriend = rf.RabaObject('Human')
```

It is optimized to have little memory consumption, it supports queries by examples, inheritance, has debugging tools and even allows you to fall back onto SQL if needed.

Comment: Not well documented, also not clear demos of complexity given.

Comment: Well I disagree. The github readme contains pretty much everything you need to know to use it. Up to debugging, transactions and even inheritance. If you are interested in complexity and performances, it is heavily dependent on SQLite's version. However, nothing is kept secret here. You can easily print the SQL queries with conn.enableQueryPrint(True) (cf. readme). If you want to have a look at the schemas, the .db files can be opened with any SQLite client, and you can use SQLite's explain to get a better look at the performances depending on your SQLite version.

Comment: Seems your disagree on your little knowledge, see how well to maintain document. https://github.com/coleifer/peewee  and also http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/, adding few samples we can't say well documented. You might conisder its document, but it just 2% of complete documentation. Just see today no-one fork or high rated RabaDb libs, I can consider your disagree is your personal. But RabaDB yet weak over utilization.

Comment: Well now you're being rude. RabaDB is not my main focus. It's pyGeno's (http://pygeno.iric.ca/) backend abstracted and shared in case someone finds it useful because of its unique qualities. Among others, RabaDB is seemlessly schemaless, a feature rarely found in ORMs. It has a simple interfaces with a unique querying method that allows for complex queries without writing a single line of SQL. I do intend to improve on the doc. In the meantime, the README has everything needed to use it. If you prefer Peewee, use it. But don't insult people's knowledge, that's not how you make things better.

Comment: Well I disagree to you 100%, Peewee is great, RABADB not well DOCUMENTED. I avoid to your scrap arguments.