# How do you filter a large dataset for records that fit a specific key, while iterating over all the elements in the dataset

Tags: python, collections

I have a large set of data which I access via a generator/iterator. While processing the dataset I need to determine if any record in that dataset has an attribute with the same value as an attribute of the current record being processed. One way to do this would be with a nested for loop. For example, if were processing a database of students, I could do something like:

```
def fillStudentList():
    # TODO: Add some code here to  filll
    # a student list
    pass

students = fillStudentList()
sameLastNames = list()
for student1 in students1:
  students2 = fillStudentList()
  for student2 in students2:
    if student1.lastName == student2.lastName:
        sameLastNames.append((student1, student2))
```

Granted the code snippet above could be improved quite a bit. The goal of the snippet is to show the nested for loop pattern.

Now let's say that we have a class Student, a class Students (which) is an iterator, and a class Source which provides access to the data in a memory efficient way (say another iterator) of sorts...

Below, I have sketched out what this code might look like. Does anyone have ideas on how to improve this implementation? The goal is to be able to find records in very large datasets with the same attributes so that that filtered set can then be processed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from itertools import ifilter

class Student(object):
    """
    A class that represents the first name, last name, and
    grade of a student.
    """
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, grade='K'):
        """
        Initializes a Student object
        """
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.grade = grade

class Students(object):
    """
    An iterator for a collection of students
    """
    def __init__(self, source):
        """
        """
        self._source = source
        self._source_iter = source.get_iter()
        self._reset = False

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        try:
            if self._reset:
                self._source_iter = self._source.get_iter()
                self._reset = False
            return self._source_iter.next()
        except StopIteration:
            self._reset = True
            raise StopIteration

    def select(self, attr, val):
        """
        Return all of the Students with a given
        attribute
        """
        #select_iter = self._source.get_iter()
        select_iter = self._source.filter(attr, val)
        for selection in select_iter:
            # if (getattr(selection, attr) == val):
            #    yield selection
            yield(selection)

class Source(object):
    """
    A source of data that can provide an iterator to 
    all of the data or provide an iterator to the
    data based on some attribute
    """
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def get_iter(self):
        """
        Return an iterator to the data
        """
        return iter(self._data)

    def filter(self, attr, val):
        """
        Return an iterator to the data filtered by some
        attribute
        """
        return ifilter(lambda rec: getattr(rec, attr) == val, self._data)

def test_it():
    """
    """
    studentList = [Student("James","Smith","6"),
                   Student("Jill","Jones","6"),
                   Student("Bill","Deep","5"),
                   Student("Bill","Sun","5")]
    source = Source(studentList)
    students = Students(source)
    for student in students:
        print student.firstName

        for same_names in students.select('firstName', student.firstName):
            if same_names.lastName == student.lastName:
                continue
            else:
                print " %s %s in grade %s has your same first name" % \
                (same_names.firstName, same_names.lastName, same_names.grade)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_it()
```

Comment: Any reason you are trying to do this manually as opposed to a database?

Comment: Unfortunately, the **Source** of the data is not just a database. Otherwise, I would let the database do the work. The **Students** class implemented above would ideally be an **Adapter** and the **Source** class a **Facade** to give clients the impression of a single data source. In reality, however, the Source would be pulling data from multiple streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested loops are O(n**2). You can instead use a sort and [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for O(nlogn) performance:

```
students = fill_student_list()
same_last_names = [list(group) for lastname, group in 
                   groupby(sorted(students, key=operator.attrgetter('lastname'))]
```

In general, you appear to be trying to do what an ORM backed by a database does. Instead of doing it yourself, use one of the many ORMs already out there. See [What are some good Python ORM solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428/what-are-some-good-python-orm-solutions) for a list. They will be both more optimized and more powerful than something you would code yourself.

Comment: I think that an Object Relational Mapping (ORM) Library is probably the best way to go. I will need to supply an Adapter to the object that is created by the ORM so that I can add attributes that are created from other sources, but that isn't too different from what I am doing now. It would be nice to use some type of graph and use a recursive algorithm to find all of the duplicates of a given attribute. For now I am going to structure the data in such a way that I can create a flag and cache the ids of duplicates. That way I can iterate over a smaller set after the initial processing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this would work for you (this is O(n))

```
from collections import defaultdict
students = fillStudentList()
sameLastNames = defaultdict(list)
for student in students:
    sameLastNames[student.lastName].append(student)

sameLastNames = {k:v for k,v in sameLastNames.iteritems() if len(v)>1}
```

Comment: This would work if all he wanted was to index the lastName attr. And he would have to keep generating the index any time a record changes. But it seems he wants to be able to "query" on any attr? And then he would have to create multiple indexes...and then...just use a database :-)

Comment: @jdi, to do it efficiently with the database you will still need to create indices on which ever attributes you are interested in. But yeah, a db query can probably handle this, and if there are only tens of thousands of records, you might not even notice if the extra indices aren't there :)

Comment: Well ya I know you would create indices for the db, but it would be a lot more efficient than this simple python approach and would always stay in sync with your records. It just seems like the more and more he would try and accomodate this pure python approach, the more he is reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @jdi, impossible to know if it's a lot more efficient or not without a lot more information. If there are a lot of attributes to check and lots of records getting returned for each one it _may_ be more efficient to suck the whole table over once. Especially if there is a slow network connection involved. Too many variables