# How do I return values from a function into sqlite3 in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm playing around with sqlite3, and when I say playing around, I mean I have no idea how to use it.  Is con.execute what you use to actually save things into the database?  How do I move george=people at the bottom of this example into sql?

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
#import sqlite3
#
#conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE COMPANY
#       (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
#       NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
#       AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
#       PHONE          CHAR(50),
#       FBLINK         TEXT    NOT NULL)
#
#conn = sqlite3.connect('addressbook.db')
#print "Opened database successfully";
#
#conn.execute("INSERT INTO PHONEBOOK (ID,NAME,AGE,PHONE,FBLINK) \
#      VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California', 20000.00 )");
#
#conn.commit()
#conn.close()

#A decorator to correct uppercase strings
def lowercasewrapper(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return [item.lower() for item in func(*args, **kwargs)]
    return wrapper

#Class with object attributes
class People():
    numofpeeps = 0
    listofpeeps = []
    def __init__(self, name, age, phone, fblink):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.phone=phone
        self.fblink=fblink
        People.numofpeeps += 1
        People.listofpeeps.append(self.name)

    @lowercasewrapper #calling the wrapper, to make all strings lowercase
    def displayPerson(self): 
        return self.name, self.age, self.phone, self.fblink

george=People("gEORge", "10 years old", "503-405-4021", "http://facebook.com/boobs")
dave=People("dave", "10", "971-863-3905", "http://boobs.com")
charlie=People("CHARLIE", "19", "823-405-2942", "http://boobs.com")

print george.displayPerson()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial you can study:

http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/

But you might also want to just use an ORM to abstract away the database details for you.  An ORM will give you a Python class, and you can just write Python code instead of database code.

[What are some good Python ORM solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428/what-are-some-good-python-orm-solutions)